# Why PrefixMap in scala examples has extends?

Tags: scala

Looking at `PrefixMap` example in scala docs [Here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl_6.html) at `object PrefixMap` (you need to scroll down a bit) I see this code:

```
object PrefixMap extends {
  def empty[T] = new PrefixMap[T]
  ....
}
```

Previously I thought that `extends {` means that `PrefixMap` extends anonymous class that defines all the members that goes after `{`. 
But it looks like I was wrong, as `PrefixMap.getClass.getSuperclass` returns `class java.lang.Object`

If I remove `extends` keyword there, I do not see any change in the behavior of an example. So why is it there, and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, if you remove the `extends` clause, nothing changes. Here is an old discussion on the topic explaining the `extends {}` syntax: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/scala-internals/13c6709rbf/deprecating-optional-extends/13c9v5r93m

This comment on the thread from Odersky explains why it is legal: http://grokbase.com/p/gg/scala-internals/13c81d0cqz/deprecating-optional-extends